# Not able to get the text entered in search bar in android

Tags: android, search, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement search functionality for my android application. I am not able to get the text entered in the search bar. I have tried all the methods mentioned in SO. Please let me know what mistake am I doing. I am struggling from a long time.

my code:

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_for_fragments, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.
                getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
      enteredText = (String) searchView.getQuery();

        Log.d("iFocus", "" + enteredText);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

       searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
               Log.d("iFocus", ""+searchView.getQuery());

               if (0 != searchView.getQuery().length()) {
                   String spnId = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                   setSearchResult(spnId);
               } else {
                   setData();
               }


               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

               Log.d("iFocus", ""+newText.toString());
               adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

               return true;
           }
       });


    }
```

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use in the overridden method onQueryTextSubmit the parameter that you become to get the query like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Log.d("iFocus", query);

    if (0 != query.length()) {
         setSearchResult(query);
    } else {
         setData();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing, searchView.getQuery is not returning me anything.

Comment: hmmm, can you please debug the code and tell me what do you get as a value of the `query` parameter in the `onQueryTextSubmit` method?

Comment: when I debug the control never goes to that method, when I enter text it should go to that method right?

Comment: I think that it will go there when you submit (from the method signature is it said) your search query. Try to tap enter after the query and it should go in the method

Answer (score 0):

See my example project with ToolBar and search menu item, min API level = 7:

[android-toolbar-search](https://github.com/Max64/android-toolbar-search)

Comment: can you please tell me how are you using serach_layout.xml?? are you inflating it in fragment?

Comment: No, I don't inflate it in code, this is android:actionLayout attribute, which means layout when expanded on click

Comment: Corrected code, try again, and dont forget to call setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onActivityCreated method

Comment: Edited answer, see example project